# I am having trouble in adding an logo in the navigation bar

Tags: html, css, node.js, reactjs, mongoose

```
I tried using the anchor tag and its not working.I also tried this,
 <h2 class="navbar-brand brand-name">
   <a href="index.html"><img class="img-responsive2"       
   src="images/DigitalPondlogo.png">DigitalPond</a>
```

but I get an error that  says that image tag is not closed.I am a beginner in bootstrap and is having hard time resolving this issue.i want to add **image as well as text(Flight Reservation System)** in the logo. I need the logo to be at the left side.

This is the existing code.

```
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark ">
          <Link to={"/"} className="navbar-brand">
          
             Booking
            </Link>
            <div className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/home"} className="nav-link">
                  <strong>Home</strong>
                </Link>
              </li>

             

              {showAdminBoard && (
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link to={"/admin"} className="nav-link">
                    <strong> Admin </strong>
                   
                  </Link>
                </li>
              )}

              {currentUser && (
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link to={"/user"} className="nav-link">
                    <strong> User</strong>
                   
                  </Link>
                </li>
              )}
            </div>

            {currentUser ? (
              <div className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link to={"/profile"} className="nav-link">
                    <strong> {currentUser.username}</strong>
                   
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <a href="/login" className="nav-link" onClick={this.logOut}>
                    <strong> LogOut</strong>
                   
                  </a>
                </li>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link to={"/login"} className="nav-link">
                    <strong>Login</strong>
                  </Link>
                </li>

                
              </div>
            )}
          </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty accurate.  Your `img` tag isn't closed. Try replacing

`<img class="img-responsive2" src="images/DigitalPondlogo.png">`

with `<img class="img-responsive2" src="images/DigitalPondlogo.png" />`

Notice the `/>` at the end of the img tag.

Comment: I added this but still image cannot load.

Comment: `     <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark ">
          <Link to={"/"} className="navbar-brand">
          <a href=""><img class="img-responsive2"       
            src="flight-logo.jpg"/></a>
          Flight Reservation System
            </Link>`
            <div className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/home"} className="nav-link">
                  <strong>Home</strong>
                </Link>
              </li> ````